# Firebase Update player Resources over time

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am developing a multiplayer online text-based game in Flutter, want to use Firebase as backend. Briefly, there are cities of the players that have buildings. Those buildings generate resources(gold, coal, etc.) over time.

To prevent cheating, I need to handle that in the backend. How should I proceed? Using cloud functions to handle it, didn't seem to be scalable to me.

Comment: "Using cloud functions to handle it, didn't seem to be scalable to me." You'll probably want to elaborate on why Cloud Functions won't work, as they're an auto-scaling backend service. For an example of how they can be used in a game, have a look at this talk from I/O 2017: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWj6dxfN63g&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLma7gxYxtEwO1rsAPn7wkV_&index=20

Comment: I wanted to mean price-wise scalability, if all of the clients sent update requests to firebase freaquently, which triggers cloud functions will be salty. Instead, I came up with writing state management fuctions with Go.  Those fuctions can either use firebase queries or local data. So I can use them in both cloud fuctions and in the phone using Gomobile. I will run this functions in phone every second but only once as a cloud function. In this way, it will be both a smooth gameplay for user, and a cost effective approach for me.